# Showing a view in WindowManager that can come from "out of screen"

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager

I'm having the following issue - I'm having a view that I'm putting inside the WindowManager
and I would like it to come in translate animation from out of the screen and toward the middle of the screen.

Unfortunately, no matter what I do the view sticks to the axis.

This is the code:

```
    view = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.poke, null);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            300, 400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.verticalMargin = -10f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    windowManager.addView(view, params);
```

As you can see I tried playing with the margin (put there minus to make it go up).

By the way - I know that it's ugly to put numbers and not dp in dimen.xml. Its just a test code..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just faced the same issue and the actual flag is:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
```

So your code should look like:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        300, 400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the flags that you are specifying, add another flag `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`.

That should allow you to place your views even outside the screen.

Your code should look like this:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
     300, 400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
     PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: there is nothing like FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_BOUNDS